# Notation complete polynomial of order two

Tags: polynomials, notation

I don't know what notation to use for a complete second order polynomial in two variables. Let's say I use the monomial basis functions:

$$
f(x)=a_1 + a_2 x_1  + a_3 x_2 + a_4 x_1^2 + a_5x_1x_2 + a_6x_2^2 
$$

But I would like to write it differently, something like this:
$$
\phi\left(x\right)  =\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{1}^{2} & x_{1}x_{2} & x_{2}^{2}\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{P}a_i\phi(x)
$$

What would be the correct way to write this?

Comment: The correct way is $
f(x_1,x_2)=a_1 + a_2 x_1  + a_3 x_2 + a_4 x_1^2 + a_5x_1x_2 + a_6x_2^2 
$, as you have written. In the other form, use $x_1^kx_2^l$ and not $\phi(x)$ and $a_{kl}$ instead of $a_i$. So $f(x,y)=\sum_{k,l}a_{kl}x_1^kx_2^l$. See [here](https://www.imsc.res.in/~kapil/geometry/prereq1/node6.html).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you! I see your point. I am so bad with notation... I am just writing the description of some computer code. So my $\phi$ is matrix, with each polynomial term in a column vector. So i would really like something like $Q=[1, x1, x2]$, and use a row vector with coefficients: $a=[a1,a2,a3]$ and then refer to the function as $f(x1,x2;a) = aQ^{\intercal}$. There should be some valid notation for that, no? I think the summation is not so clear?

Comment: It's a common practice to write as **quadratic forms** as in conics
$$0=f(x,y)\equiv
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & y & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & h & g \\
  h & b & f \\
  g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
or quadrics
$$0=F(x,y,z) \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z & 1 \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & h & g & i \\
    h & b & f & j \\
    g & f & c & k \\
    i & j & k & d
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ z \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks @NgChungTak that is also intresting. So according to this notation it would also be 'correct' to write: $f(x,y) =\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}1& x & y & x^2 & xy & y^2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\a_6\end{array}\right)$? Or is there some problem doing that? And if correct, how can i refer to a column in $\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}1& x & y & x^2 & xy & y^2\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: It depends on the contexts.  Your choice is **monomial bases**.  In quadratic forms, we can transform them into **eigenbases**.

Comment: BTW, dot products are associative, i.e. $$\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{a}=\boldsymbol{a}^T \boldsymbol{x}$$